# Firebase Firestore - Saving user bookmarks

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm migrating my app over to Firebase Firestore and I'm running into issues on how to implement bookmarking. Each user can bookmark/favorite any number of events within my app, and I want to be able to store and retrieve these.

For bookmarking, I'm trying to to grab the user id ( using Firebase Anonymous sign in ), and create a document containing `true`.

```
fun bookmark(event: Event) {
    val userId = "my-user-id"

    val document = firestore
            .collection(USERS)
            .document(userId)
            .collection(BOOKMARKS)
            .document(event.id)

    if (event.isBookmarked) {
        document.set(event.id to true)
    } else {
        document.delete()
    }
}
```

I think this is almost right, as it creates a document at `users/my-user-id/bookmarks/my_event_id`, but it's a pair.

```
first: "my_event_id"
second: true
```

As for retrieving the bookmarks, I'm a bit unsure what I should do for this. I think I should do multiple fetches and set them, but I'm wondering if there may be a better way to do this.

```
fun getEvents(): LiveData<List<FirebaseEvent>>{
    firestore
            .collection(EVENTS)
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
                if (exception == null) {
                    val events = snapshot?.toObjects(FirebaseEvent::class.java)
                    // TODO fetch the bookmarks and set those here
                    mutableLiveData.postValue(events)
                }
            }

    return mutableLiveData
}
```

Also, is this secure? Other users would be able to just guess other user IDs and see their bookmarks, correct?

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Comment: @AlexMamo I would disagree this is a duplicate of that question. They're asking about how to return items, I'm asking how to do multiple calls that depend on each other, and about architecture. I can already fetch a list of events fine, the questions is about best practices on fetching a list, and fetching all the bookmarked items and merging the two.